# NOINDEX or NOINDEX,FOLLOW

Tags: meta-tags

What is the difference between following tags?

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

Answer (score 3):

They are functionally the same.

With:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
```

there is no FOLLOW or NOFOLLOW so the default is FOLLOW which is equal to:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

Both are functionally the same and neither is incorrect, however, if you are mechanizing this meta-tag, I would suggest the more complete:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

Comment: Google now says that "follow" is useless with "noindex".   If you are using "noindex", the links on the page eventually get ignored anyway.  [Google: Long Term Noindex Will Lead To Nofollow Also](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-long-term-noindex-follow-24990.html)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Okay. I can see if the page is not indexed, then a filter cannot get the links from the page. Except we know this process does happen. I read the linked page and it does not make sense. I appreciate the link, however, what was said is so fuzzy, it does not sound possible. Computers do the smae thing over and over. They do not reason like humans do. John says on one hand the page will exist in the index and then they think eventually you really mean it so the behaviour changes? That is why I hated people quoting Matt Cutts. Most of the time they just read what they wanted.

Comment: I take it to mean that the PageRank calculation is only performed against pages in the index.    So when you tell Google not to index a page, it won't be included in the PageRank calculation.   Because the PageRank calculation job and the indexing job run separately, they could be a time when the page is noindexed, but still available to the PageRank calculation, but eventually it will get completely kicked out of the index and not available for PageRank calculations.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I really can see not indexing links for a page you were explicitly forbidden to index. This is not a good business decision. It is always better to keep a URL (page in this case), so that any link with that page as a source or target of could be understood. I get the notion of dumping the HTML source of course. From a business perspective, the core of the schema has to be absolutely reliable. That would be the URL (page) and link index (tables). And you would think it wise to know as much as possible so that decisions can be made once and not over and over again.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but there are many times that Google doesn't work the way I would have assumed that it does.   I generally see people trying to use `noindex,follow` to game the system and Google may have put something in to react to that.    Or maybe John's somewhat vague statement isn't the whole story.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Aaahhh... PR, that would make total sense! Noindex should break PR passing through the page. Noindex, in my mind, means I get no benefit at all and to expect anything different is just plain silly!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That is a new one! How would noindex, follow even be thought to game the system?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller BTW- is it a sin to be on SE during church? Is it worse using their WiFi? ... It is a good thing I am at home today!

Comment: I wait until I'm home from church.  It wouldn't look good to be up front in the choir on SE.   Folks try to use `noindex,follow` to sculpt PR.  "Don't index this page, but give a boost to the pages it links to."

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I get it now... except that still doesn't not make sense from a strategy point of view. You only get a fraction of PR passing through a link and a small fraction at that! Silly wabbits!! Do not start singing an SE post instead of a hymm. Unless you sing harmony!